# git diff from deleted and re-created files

Tags: git, diff

I am monitoring changes to files that are automatically generated every day through git from a legacy system. Git reports these changes as a deleted file then a created file. I was wondering if it was possible for git to record it as a change, as the file is 99% the same with some minor changes.

I will note files that get deleted and re-created with no changes git does not detect as a change.

I run `git add .` and commited and thought that I would get a change of the file, instead it records the entry as a deleted file and a re-created file.

Comment: Please may you add some commands used and their output? It'd be good to add more information so we can have a better understanding of the issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.